# JavaScript: create a function within a specific scope

Tags: javascript, function, scope

JavaScript: I need create a function within a specific scope. 
The function to be created, is generated dynamically by a previous process of code generation. And the scope for the definition of this function may also change.

Look this example:

```
var createFnInOtherScope = function() {
    console.debug('createFnInOtherScope: Who I am', this);

    //This code can not be modified because it's dynamically generated
    function MyFunction() {
            console.debug('MyFunction');
    }
}
var obInitial = {
    createFn: function() {
        console.debug('createFn: Who I am', this);
        createFnInOtherScope.call(window);
    }
}
obInitial.createFn();

//ReferenceError: MyFunction is not defined
window.MyFunction();
```

How I can do this?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you are asking to add to a function to the global scope.  Some comments on answers below address this.  If you are looking for a more flexable approach, you should look into MONADs (permission given/denied on the fly).

Comment: Please define what _you_ mean by "scope", because it doesn't appear to be the usual JS definition (which is _lexical scope_).

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, what you're asking is impossible.

Scope in Javascript is a *lexical* construct, meaning that what's in scope is defined by its physical location (at parse time) in the source file with respect to any enclosing functions.

You can't retrospectively add something into a scope once that scope has (lexically) been closed off.

Comment: yeah, but the _default_ (implicit) scope for _any_ variable definition  is `window` right?  So as long as you say `myFunction = function...`  rather than `function myFunction...`, it should ( and does appear to ) work.

Comment: @DanFarrell that's not "scope", that's just how global variables become properties of `window`.  A variable defined with `var` doesn't become a property of anything.

Comment: OK, good point.  The function is _in_ scope, but _its_ scope is not altered.

Comment: @DanFarrell not even that.  Every function and declaration is in scope of the global JS _environment_ (i.e. the top level scope that all `<script>` elements share) but that's not the same thing as `window`, which is just an object.

Comment: @DanFarrell the only exception is that variables that aren't found by normal traversal of the lexical scope chain are looked up as properties of `window`, but this confuses the distinction between _lexical scope_ and _variable resolution scope_.

Answer (score 0):

Function scope is defined at parse time. You can create a function and make it visible as a `window` property:

```
function outer() {
  function inner() {
    console.log("hello world");
  }

  window.inner = inner;
}

window.inner(); // hello world
```

But that does not alter the scope of the "inner" function. It's *visible* and *callable* via the global object, but the function is unalterably in the scope of that "outer" function.

Answer (score 0):

Just define this function in `this` context:

```
var createFnInOtherScope = function() {
    this.MyFunction = function() {
        console.debug('MyFunction');
    };
};
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Ur6vF/

Comment: `this` is not a _scope_, it's a _context_.

Comment: @Alnitak I was just about to rename `this` as *object* instead. I think it describes the case better but maybe less correctly. So most probably you are right and *context* is the best word.